# Is Django supposed to get so slow with around 250 000 model's objects?

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite

I am doing some small project but with around 250 000 model's objects. I have my car model and I am importing data from external json. I talked with some people and they told me that 250 000 objects in django is not a big amount and it won't have much impact on performance.

Loading up to models this data from json is takin around 5 - 10 min and I don't mind that. But, right now If I make any changes to the website (locally) while running `runserver` I have to wait around 1 minute (on macbook pro 2020 (not M1)). And it is pretty annoying.

I ran command `python -v manage.py check` and apparently `django.db.models.sql.compiler` takes this whole time.

I am wondering, if my approach with models is wrong, or it is normal with SQL Light?

Or maybe I could safely turn off this check? Or I got wrong informations and workflow with this many model's object is totally wrong?

cProfile sorted by tottime:

```
236646 function calls (229052 primitive calls) in 50.709 seconds
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        9   50.280    5.587   50.280    5.587 {built-in method posix.waitpid}
    6    0.067    0.011    0.067    0.011 {built-in method time.sleep}
  466    0.041    0.000    0.041    0.000 {built-in method marshal.loads}
   32    0.031    0.001    0.032    0.001 {built-in method _imp.create_dynamic}
```

1713/1614    0.026    0.000    0.099    0.000 {built-in method builtins.**build_class**}
2235    0.022    0.000    0.022    0.000 {built-in method posix.stat}
466    0.020    0.000    0.020    0.000 {built-in method io.open_code}

cProfile sorted by cumtime:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
495/1    0.003    0.000   63.643   63.643 {built-in method builtins.exec}
    1    0.000    0.000   63.643   63.643 manage.py:2(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000   63.643   63.643 manage.py:7(main)
    1    0.000    0.000   63.549   63.549 __init__.py:398(execute_from_command_line)
    1    0.000    0.000   63.549   63.549 __init__.py:321(execute)
    2    0.000    0.000   63.304   31.652 subprocess.py:448(run)
    1    0.000    0.000   63.302   63.302 base.py:313(run_from_argv)
    1    0.000    0.000   63.300   63.300 runserver.py:55(execute)
    1    0.000    0.000   63.300   63.300 base.py:349(execute)
    1    0.000    0.000   63.300   63.300 runserver.py:67(handle)
    1    0.000    0.000   63.300   63.300 runserver.py:98(run)
    1    0.000    0.000   63.300   63.300 autoreload.py:608(run_with_reloader)
    1    0.000    0.000   63.300   63.300 autoreload.py:240(restart_with_reloader)
    2    0.000    0.000   63.300   31.650 subprocess.py:980(communicate)
    3    0.000    0.000   63.297   21.099 subprocess.py:1074(wait)
    4    0.000    0.000   63.297   15.824 subprocess.py:1772(_wait)
    9    0.000    0.000   63.227    7.025 subprocess.py:1759(_try_wait)
    9   63.227    7.025   63.227    7.025 {built-in method posix.waitpid}
   65    0.001    0.000    0.678    0.010 __init__.py:1(<module>)
```

Comment: Profiling your code (https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) would provide more useful information here, one can hardly answer your question as is. eg. `python -m cProfile -o profile.out manage.py runserver`

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I read this profile.out file? Google is proposing only custom bat solution.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#instant-user-s-manual
Please add relevant code to your post once you identified the most time consuming functions.

Comment: Thank you, I updated post. So this 'built-in method posix.waitpid' is a problem apparently?

Comment: this is not very relevant, as `waitpid` is just the indication something is waiting for a child process to terminate

Comment: I added more Procfile details, sorted by two times, maybe some of this will help?

Answer (score 1):

A conveniant solution for profiling is [django-debug-toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It shows DB queries, and it can even profile your Python code.

The profiler is disabled by default though, you have to enable it -[see docs](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/panels.html#debug_toolbar.panels.profiling.ProfilingPanel).

Comment: Hi, I installed this debug-toolbar. Can you please tell me how can I use it to determine what is taking so long while performing checks ?